# Як перекласти слово formatter у контексті системи Drupal?

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

В [Словнику спірних слів перекладачів Drupal](https://localize.drupal.org/node/186) ми намагаємось стандартизувати і стабілізувати переклади слів, які не до кінця ясно перекладені українською.

Слово *formatter* перекладаємо як *форматер*. Але це не переклад, а по суті транслітерація. В Drupal *formatter* - це здатність сутності надавати форму налаштувань, вміння відображати сутність, поле, тип матеріалу згідно форми налаштувань.

Суть терміну така: Існує контент тип, у якого є поля. У кожного поля є формат відображення на формі редагування і формат відображення на сторінці перегляду контент типу (статті). Форматер - це об'єкт, плагін, який забезпечує даний функціонал

[image]

Comment: Немає нічого поганого в тому, що ви перекладаєте це слово за допомогою транскрипції. Адже він по-суті є вузькоспеціалізованим технічним терміном, а отже, сфера його використання обмежена та розрахована на професійне коло людей (розробників), для яких він має означення та є зрозумілим.

Comment: в інтерфейсі він не названий форматером, в цьому саме. Це слово використовується в інших місцях. Я мав на меті показати, як воно працює, щоб внести смисли

Answer (score 7):

Термін *формате́р* зустрічається в декількох словниках:

[Орфографічному словнику української мови](http://slovnyk.ua/?swrd=%F4%EE%F0%EC%E0%F2%E5%F0&x=0&y=0).

В [російській версії](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) Вікісловника (де у слова *форматер* немає синонімів).

В [Тлумачному словнику з інформатики та інформаційних систем для економістів](http://computer_science_ukr.academic.ru/355/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%C3%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) у значеннях:

1. Програма або частина системи підготування текстів, яка виконує форматування.
2. Програма або пристрій, призначені для розмічування магнітних дисків.

Синомімів-іменників знайти не вдалось, проте, можу запропонувати варіанти перекладу *формат виводу* або *формат представлення*.

Comment: Тоді форматер взагалі не підходить

Comment: Тому що форматування в контексті магнітних дисків це зовсім не formatter, про який мається наувазі в запитанні
Formatter виконує роль відображення, дизайну виводу інформації

Answer (score 1):

Якщо брати до уваги ресурси, представлені у відповіддях вище, то у кожному випадку вживання слова `форматер` має свій контекст.

У випадку з Drupal краще буде залишити слово `форматер` (по суті транслітерацію), адже воно вживається природньо у контексті Drupal і відповідає своєму загальному значенню.

Comment: -1: ця відповідь не додає ніякої нової інформації, порівняно з іншими відповідями, але натомість містить особисту думку автора. Будь ласка, перегляньте [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5/) щодо того, які дописи ми вважаємо хорошими, а які — ні.

Comment: добре, дякую за зауваження. Надалі буду аргументовано відповідати з урахуванням критеріїв.